# Stata timeseries rolling forecast

Tags: time-series, stata

I'm new to Stata and have a question about its command language.  I want to use my ARIMA model to forecast, ie use x[t], x[t-1]... to produce an estimate xhat[t+1], and then roll forward one time step, to make the next forecast, rebuilding the model every N time steps.

i can duplicate code, something like the following code for T, T+1, T+2, etc.:

```
 arima x if t<=T, arima(2,0,2)
 predict xhat
```

to produce a series of xhats to compare with in-sample x observations.   There must be a more natural way to do this in the command language.  any suggestions, pointers would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Indeed: the help for `arima` points you to `rolling` as a prefix command.

Answer (score 2):

Posting a working solution provided by Stata tech support:

```
webuse dfex
tsset month
generate int id = _n

capture program drop forecarima
program forecarima, rclass
        syntax [if]
        tempvar yhat
        arima unemp `if', arima(1,1,0)
        local T = e(tmax)
        local T1 = `T' + 1
        summarize id if month == `T1'
        local h = r(max)
        predict `yhat', y dynamic(`T')
        return scalar y = unemp[`h']
        return scalar yhat = `yhat'[`h']
end

rolling unemp = r(y) unemp_hat = r(yhat), window(400) recursive ///
        saving(results,replace): forecarima 
use results,clear
browse
```

this provides output with the prediction and observed both available.  the dates are off by one step, but easier left to post-processing.